# location aware ads us20130046636

Tags: law, us20130046636

Does this patent only cover the US or will it relate to similar systems worldwide?
at what date will this current patent expire?

Answer (score 1):

This is a publication of a patent **application** not a granted patent. They are formatted the same but in the upper right hand corner is says Publication No. rather than Patent No.

Looking this up in the USPTO Public PAIR database, this application has not yet been examined.

Patents are territorial. A US patent can only be enforced in US Federal Court. Often an inventor files counterpart applications in multiple countries.